# How to make Box with outer row count?

Tags: box, java, count

can someone tell me how to make the following picture in Latex?
Especially the box and the outer row count?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: See the `listings` package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation of the `listing` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) contains many examples. A starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{frame=single,numbers=left,language=java,basicstyle=\ttfamily,captionpos=b}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Attribute der Klasse \texttt{BankAccount}}]
class BankAccount {
    String name;
    Hamster hamster;
    Integer grainNumber;
    Integer maximumOverdraft;
    
    [...]
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @campa !!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `minted`+`tcolorbox` approach. Peruse their documentation to change the aspect. Remember to run `pdflatex` (or any other engine) with the `-shell-escape` option. You also need `pygmentize` on your system (it's a Python add-on).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\NewTCBListing{java}{O{}}
 {
  left=2pt,
  minted language=java,
  minted options={linenos,#1},
  listing only,
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[htp]

\begin{java}
class BankAccount {
    String name;
    Hamster hamster;
    Integer grainNumber;
    Integer maximumOverdraft;
    
    [...]
\end{java}

\caption{Attribute der Klasse \texttt{BankAccount}\label{bankaccount}}

\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

The environment has an optional argument to set, if needed, further `minted` options.

If you're running a version of LaTeX prior to the 2020-10-01 release, you also need

```
\usepackage{xparse}
```

[image]